# IBM MQ | Connection Disruption | Message Loss

Tags: .net, client-server, ibm-mq

**Summary**

.Net client using IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.2.5.0 reading messages from MQ server.  When the .net client temporarily loses network connectivity to the MQ server, I experience message loss.  I am unable to find any traces of the lost messages making it to the .net client's user code.  I suspect the message loss is occurring somewhere between the IBMXMSDotnetClient library and the MQ server.

```
var session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge);
var queue = session.CreateQueue(_queueName);
var consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queue);
consumer.MessageListener = message =>
{
  if (!(message is ITextMessage recvMsg)) return;

  var xml = recvMsg.Text;
  // process message
  message.Acknowledge();
};
```

**MQ Client Global Exception Listener**

IBM.XMS.XMSException: MQ delivered an asynchronous event with completion code 0, and reason 2545.  XMSWMQ2014.explanation  XMSWMQ2014.useraction  Linked Exception : CompCode: 0, Reason: 2545

Anyone have similar experience or advice on troubleshooting?

Comment: Are the messages persistent or non-persistent?

Comment: non-persistent.

Comment: Then this behavior would be expected.   If you need to recover with no message loss you need to use persistent messages.